# CAS SSO - Override LDAPHandler

Tags: authentication, spring-security, ldap, single-sign-on, cas

I am working on setup of CAS SSO using cas-overalay-template. Integrated LDAP for authentication.

By Default the request goes through LDAPAuthenticatiionHandler and returns the HandlerResult.

My Requirement is to Have a CustomLDAPAuthenticationHandler and post to successful authentication, I need to make a REST call to populate more data/fields into CAS Authentication Response data.

Now, is there any way that I can mark my CustomLDAPAuthenticationHandler as default LDAPAuthenticationHandler?

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

> ...post to successful authentication, I need to make a REST call to populate more data/fields into CAS Authentication Response data.

Rather than duplicating an LDAP authentication handler, only to then do stuff that has nothing to do with LDAP afterward, you're better off leaving the LDAP handler alone and simply make the REST call separately to populate attributes, etc from external sources.

[This post](https://apereo.github.io/2019/06/12/cas61x-rest-api/) should provide an explanation on how that might be done, using RESTful Attribute Resolution.